# Is there a way to refresh screen in MIT App Inventor 2?

Tags: app-inventor

I have a button and when clicked, sends the data to google sheet. Immediately, I need to see the result which I sent on my screen but that only works when I refresh the screen manually.
`Call Web.Get` doesn't work. May I know if there is a way to refresh the screen after a button click?

I tried `open another screen screenName = current screen`, but that didn't help either.

Comment: What about providing a screenshot of your relevant blocks? Please edit your question accordingly. Why does the Web.Get not work? You might want to call it a little bit later, for example 1 second later... try a clock component to do it later...

Comment: I will try that. Thanks